# Numerical Integration of a special integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to numerically compute an integral of the following form
$$\int_0^{\infty}(\int^1_0J_0(v\rho)\cos(\rho^2/2)\rho\,d\rho)^2\,v\,dv$$

where $J_0(x)$ is the zero-th order Bessel function, BesselJ[0,x] in Mathematica. As there is a square of integral in variable that needs to be done numerically before integrating another variable numerically, the function $\textbf{NIntegrate}$ seems do not work, anyone know how to deal with integrals of this form numerically using functions of Mathematica?

Comment: Use iteratively `NIntegrate[y*(Integrate[x*f[x,y],{x,0,1}])^2,{y,0,1}]`. `Integrate` does numerical integration too, just first does analytical...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Thank you, but this seems does not work. The description of the cause in Mathematica is similar as when you numerically integrate Cos(c x) for x in (0,1) and c is a constant.

Comment: It could be helpful if you specify what is `f[x,y]`definition

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I have edited the question and $f$ is given in it.

Comment: I have faced several times with this kind of integrals. Unfortunately, MMA does not help to solve that inside, I had to go over analytical techniques to solve it manually. Maybe someone can provide a solution I am not able to see...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Thank you very much. Yes, the only idea I have is also to solve it manually.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313928276_The_Optical_Transfer_Function_and_the_Meijer-G_function)

Comment: If you switch the order of integration, the `v` integral looks a lot like a `HankelTransform` (introduced in 11.1)! Not sure if it's possible with the squared integral though.